# How to automatically map multipart/form-data input to a bean in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a Jersey REST api that receives inputs as multipart/form-data. The signature is as follows:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/getorders")
public Response getOrders(final FormDataMultiPart request) {
```

The input parameters in the form are:

```
clientName
orderType
year
```

I would like instead to have something like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/getOrders")
public Response getOrders(final OrderBean order) {
```

And get all my inputs in a bean like this:

```
public class OrderBean {

    private String clientName;
    private int orderType;
    private int year;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Is there a way to do that automatically with Jersey? I know that I can map the fields manually and fill in the bean, but actually I'm looking for an annotation or something like that, that can fill in the bean automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey supports `@FormDataParam`s in a `@BeanParam` bean. If you were to do this (as you would see in most examples):

```
@POST
public Response post(@FormDataParam("clientName") String clientName) {}
```

Then you can also do

```
class OrderBean {
  @FormDataParam("clientName")
  private String clientName;

  // getter/setters
}

@POST
public Response post(@BeanParam OrderBean order) {}
```