# Is there a method to read form data from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm receiving the Form Data by adding `@FormDataParam` to a parameter of the REST Interface.

Our companies code guidelines state, that we should not use more then 7 parameters in a method. So I would like to reduce the number of parameters for this REST Interface.

```java
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response upload(@Context final HttpServletRequest request, @FormDataParam("file") final java.io.File file, @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData, @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataBodyPart formDataBodyPart, @FormDataParam("networksegments") final String networksegments, @FormDataParam("users") final String users, @FormDataParam("username") final String username, @FormDataParam("token") final String token) {
    //Some code
}
```

I´m searching for a method like `request.getFormData("name")` to make the parameter obsolete. The above code is working fine, I want optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create you own bean with `@FormDataParam` parameters and add to [bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251290/how-to-automatically-map-multipart-form-data-input-to-a-bean-in-jersey/42251460#42251460) and then use one `@BeanParam` for all parameters in endpoint

> ```
> class OrderBean {
>    @FormDataParam("clientName")
>     private String clientName;
>   // getter/setters
>   }
>
> @POST
>   public Response post(@BeanParam OrderBean order) {}
> ```